# rails 3.2 to_date monkey patching & Mongoid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have put a small monkey patch to allow for better String.to_date handling. It works great on strings but it seems mongoid has its own method for trying to convert the string into a date. I am doing this because ruby expects a "DD/MM/YY" where my monkey patch will allow for any localized date format and covert it to a Date object.

I need to do a similar monkey patch to Mongoid.

**app/config/initializers/string_to_date_monkey_match.rb**

```
class String
  def to_date
    Chronic.parse(self).to_date
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [home_run](https://github.com/jeremyevans/home_run) gem. It lets you specify a default time format